# Why does Intel Debugger(idb) crash when attaching to running python process?

Tags: python, c++, debugging

I have C++ code wrapped in Python that I'm debugging in a Linux environment.  In order to get to the C++ code and step through it, I'd like to use the gui version of idb.  To pause the process, I drop a pdb.set_trace() in the code and then try to attach idb when the python code is sitting at the pdb breakpoint.  This causes idb to crash.  Seemingly different warning/errors appear in the idb output window each time, but idb crashes too quickly for me to capture them.

However, I am able to instead continue from the python breakpoint and quickly attach idb to the process. idb then properly loads debug symbols and lets me step through the C++ code.

I'm not really satisfied with this non-deterministic way of stepping into my C++ code and was hoping for a better way that doesn't involve me racing the computer and preserves the eye-candyness of idb.